# Java not using Import

Tags: java, import, lwjgl

Even though I have the library imported Java doesn't recognize the function. If I call the function over the library directly it's working fine.

Like that it's not working:

```
import org.lwjgl.stb.STBImage;

ByteBuffer data = stbi_load(filename, width, height, comp, 4);
```

That just works fine:

```
ByteBuffer data = org.lwjgl.stb.STBImage.stbi_load(filename, width, height, comp, 4);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing a **class**, so you should refer to the method via its class:

```
ByteBuffer data = STBImage.stbi_load(filename, width, height, comp, 4);
```

Alternatively, if you want to call the method without the class name, you should statically import the method:

```
import static org.lwjgl.stb.STBImage.stbi_load;
```

And, of course, you could use a wildcard:

```
import static org.lwjgl.stb.STBImage.*;
```

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but I’m pretty sure you’re only supposed to have one `import` keyword in an import statement. I could be wrong, I haven’t recently read the JLS for this.

Comment: @vandench yes, you are correct. Got caught up in my train of thought. Edited and fixed.